# NavBar title hidden behind CAGradientLayer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I would like to add gradient layer to my navbar, but after I add it, layer hides my title, like its behind that new sublayer.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "My Trips"
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.white]
    //self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 1)
    setupGradient()
}

let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

func setupGradient() {
    gradientLayer.colors = [
        UIColor(red: 0.259, green: 0.188, blue: 0.475, alpha: 1).cgColor,
        UIColor(red: 0.11, green: 0.024, blue: 0.369, alpha: 1).cgColor
    ]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0, 1]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.25, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.75, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(a: 0, b: 0.58, c: -0.58, d: 0, tx: 0.5, ty: 0))
    gradientLayer.bounds = (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds.insetBy(dx: -0.01*view.bounds.size.width, dy: -1*view.bounds.size.height))!
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this line for inserting layer.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews.first?.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
```